# Should compatibility questions be allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions

Somebody recently asked a question, [Connecting a touch panel display to the Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/261/46). The asker is asking if a touchscreen is compatible with the Raspberry Pi.

> Has anyone tried connecting one of these panels to the Pi yet?

There are also questions asking if **software** is compatible. Such as this question, [problems running Stella (atari emulator)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/412/46).

> Has anyone managed to run Stella properly on the device?

Should compatibility questions about **hardware, software, or both** be **allowed or disallowed?**

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think we should allow them for the moment.

Resting on our laurels may not be a good idea, but I see no harm in the two questions you reference.

If we find that we are getting loads of questions "Is this compatible?" "Is that compatible?", then perhaps we should change our minds, but I can't see anything wrong at the mo.

Well that's my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I think they should not be allowed, because potentially there could be a separate question for every model.

Probably better to have one (community-wiki, and possibly locked) question, something like "where can I find a list of touchscreens that are known to be compatible with the RasPi?"

Comment: Good idea, how about the software issue?